# mixing asp and html codes

Tags: html, asp-classic

i have this code which contains html and asp code

```
  <%for each x in rs.Fields%>
  <%IF (x.name="ID") THEN%>
  <%dim i 
  i=x.value%>
  <td><a href="form7.asp?id="+<%i%>>
  <%Response.Write(x.value)%><a/>
```

i want to use the i variable inside the html code

or another example

```
    <%id=request("id")%>
    <%=id%>

      <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <td><input name="n"></input></td>
```

i want to use id in the input tag in the value as value=id

how to do that ? can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

First, a basic ASP design principle: try to minimize the switching between HTML context and ASP (or really, VBScript) context on a page, for reasons of performance as well as readability.

Following that principle in your latter snippet, I would use Response.Write to emit the necessary HTML as follows:

```
<%
id=request("id")
Response.Write "<tr><th>Name:</th><td><input name=""n"" value=" & id & "></input></td></tr>"
%>
```

All you're doing is supplying the VALUE attribute of the INPUT tag.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
<%
dim i
for each x in rs.Fields
IF (x.name="ID") THEN
  i=x.value
  response.write("<td><a href='form7.asp?id=" & i & "'>"
  response.write(x.value) & "<a/>"
  'not sure if you want a closing TD here
  response.write("</td>") & vbCrLf
END IF
next
%>
```

Comment: If this worked for you please accept the answer for the other users to see clearly that this helped answer your question.